# Derivative of a complex vector

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative

I am trying to compute the derivative below:

$\frac{\partial \sum_{k=1}^K \ln \left({\bf x}_k^H {\bf A}{\bf x}_k \right)}{\partial {\bf x}_k^*}$,
where ${\bf x}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 1}$ and ${\bf A}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$ symmetric matrix with rank 1.

Can we use the fact that $\frac{\partial {\bf x}_k^H {\bf A}{\bf x}_k }{\partial {\bf x}_k^*}={\bf A}{\bf x}_k$, to obtain the derivative of the sum of log function of it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated question. Without further context and details of your attempts towards a solution, you are very unlikely to get an answer in MSE.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have elaborated on the question.

Comment: I understand that you have added a step towards a solution. Now, how about adding some contexts? Like where you got this problem? What are the variables $\mathbf{x}^H$ and $\mathbf{x}^*$ ? What is $K$ here?